# Can't connect to RDS in deployed App Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Laravel application that is connected to a RDS db, in localhost it works perfectly but when I deploy the application into Elastic Beanstalk it stops working.

The connection to mysql:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => 'dbpassword',
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=dbname.ctwrtyncfghj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=dbUser
```

To deploy I compress all the files except for vendor/.

Comment: What's the error you're having?

Answer (score 3):

I resolve this problem so I'm going to write the solution that takes 2 steps:

### 1. RDS connection from Laravel accordingly to AWS Documentation needs to be done like this:

a.  Add define statements in config/database.php:

```
define('RDS_HOSTNAME', $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME']);
define('RDS_USERNAME', $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME']);
define('RDS_PASSWORD', $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD']);
define('RDS_DB_NAME', $_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME']);
define('RDS_PORT', $_SERVER['RDS_PORT']);
```

b.  and change mysql config:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => RDS_HOSTNAME,
            'port' => RDS_PORT,
            'database' => RDS_DB_NAME,
            'username' => RDS_USERNAME,
            'password' => RDS_PASSWORD,
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ]
```

### 2. RDS connection from an AWS EB App needs to be thought a VPC (https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/vpc/):

a.  This is a video that shows exactly how to configure your VPC and Subnets     exactly to use EB

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udY8x_g0dTk&frags=pl%2Cwn

b.  After creating your VPC and Subnets you need to create a BRAND NEW EB      environment and connected to your VPC and Subnets

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CB6YzVBxiL4&frags=pl%2Cwn